# Update database in PHP using AJAX on click of button. What should I put in data tab?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

This is what my PHP file looks like and I want to run this on a click of a button

```
<?php
 
        include("connection.php");
    include("formulaYT.php");
        
        $query = "UPDATE `songs` SET `views` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE link = '".currentViews($soHigh)."'";
        
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        
  
?>
```

Following is my ajax code. What should I put in ajax 'data:'.

```
<body>

    <button class="buttonTest">
      Test
    </button>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

$(".buttonTest").click(function()
{
    
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "updatedatabase.php",
  data: { content: $(".buttonTest").val() }
});

});
    </script>
```

I have tried finding it on other forums but couldn't figure out anything at all

Comment: What's yourr exact question about this? What have you tried to check why the given code does not work as expected?

Comment: Also, be warned that your SQL statement is widely open for injection. Better use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

the **"data"** option is what you send to the php script with the **$ _POST** function.
If you have nothing to send (as in your case) **just don't use the "data" option**

**try this:**

file.html

```
<button type="button">TEST</button>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){ //the ajax starts only when the button 
                                  //identified by "type = button" is clicked

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',                 //type post (like php function $_POST)
            url: 'updatedatabase.php',       //your file
            success: function(data) {   //what to do when the php script it's done
                alert(data);
                $("p").text(data);       //inside the <p></p> it will print
                                         // the echo, in this case "done!"

               }
           });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

**ATTENTION!** because the database queries **are not** safe, you can do **sql injection** attacks as they are now.
I suggest you to **correct** them!

updatedatabase.php

```
  <?php

  include("connection.php");
  include("formulaYT.php");
    
  $query = "UPDATE `songs` SET `views` = 
  '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE link = 
  '".currentViews($soHigh)."'";
    
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    
    echo "done!"   //all it's done

   ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added some comments in the JS code

Comment: Please never, never, never recommend the usage of unsecure database queries

Comment: @NicoHaase the queries were not made by me, and I didn't recommend them, I copied and pasted the php script.
the queries were made by whoever asked the question, I only edited ajax